# WebDriverException occurs if without sudo option

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sudo

I'm encountering `WebDriverException` ever since the chrome version has been updated.
Thing is, the error occurs only when I'm not using `sudo` option.
I need to run this code in Jupiter notebook (which I can't use sudo option, I guess??)

Can anyone plz let me know the solution?!
Thanks ahead...

This is my code below

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_options = Options()
ua = UserAgent(verify_ssl=False)
userAgent = ua.random

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-gpu')  
chrome_options.add_argument('lang=ko_KR')  
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/xx/xxx/xxxx/chromedriver-103',
                      options=chrome_options)
```

And this is my error message below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3a252780e886> in <module>
     12 
     13 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/fds_pl/shellCompany/source/chromedriver-103',
---> 14                       options=chrome_options)

~/yerinvirtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     79                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     80                     keep_alive=keep_alive),
---> 81                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     82         except Exception:
     83             self.quit()

~/yerinvirtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/yerinvirtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~/yerinvirtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/yerinvirtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

Comment: Add this option `chrome_options.add_argument("--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp")`

Comment: Show also your driver logs

Comment: @YerinJung I see you commented that the answer worked for you, why did you delete it?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Have no idea why it deleted... thanks!!

Comment: @YerinJung no problem, could you consider accepting my answer by clicking on the check mark left of the answer box please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the option

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp")
```